# What are some alternatives to the sentence "I've recently suffered an injury"?

Tags: sentence-choice

I myself was thinking of a few sentences, but wasn't sure if they were grammatically correct.

"I've recently incurred an injury"

"I've recently sustained an injury"

Answer (score 2):

All 3 versions are equally good and grammatically correct.

Alternatively you could say "*I've recently been injured*"

This is one of the few cases where the word order does not appear to be that critical. All of the following are grammatically correct and mean much the same thing.

- I've recently been injured
- Recently I've been injured
- I've been injured recently

Comment: *Injured recently I have been.* ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford Believe it or not I nearly put the Yoda version into my answer,